# Ruby splitting string into different files

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, substring

Here I've created an algorithm that extracts an array of the Federalist papers and splits them up saving them into separate files titled "Federalist No." followed by their respective numbers. Everything works perfectly and the files are being created beautifully; however, the only problem I run into now is that it fails to create the last output. 
Maybe it's because I've been staring at this for too many hours but I'm at an impasse. 
I've inserted the line `puts fedSections.length` to see what the output is.
Using a smaller version of the compilation of the Fed papers for testing, the terminal output is 3... it creates "Federalist No. 0" a blank document to take into account empty space and "Federalist No. 1" with the first federalist paper. No "Federalist No. 2."

Any thoughts?

```
# Create new string to add array l to 
fedString = " "


for f in 0...l.length-1 
    fedString += l[f] + ''
end

# Create variables applied to new files

Federalist_No= "Federalist No." 
a = "0"
b = "FEDERALIST No."    


fedSections = Array.new() # New array to insert Federalist paper to 
fedSections = fedString.split("FEDERALIST No.")  # Split string into elements of the array at each change in Federalist paper
puts fedSections.length

# Split gives empty string, off by one

for k in 0...fedSections.length-1 # Use of loop to write each Fed paper to its own file
    new_text = File.open(Federalist_No + a + ".txt", "w") # Open said file with write capabilities
    new_text.puts(b+a) # Write the "FEDERALIST No" and the number from "a"
    new_text.puts fedSections[k] # Write contents of string (section of paper) to a file
    new_text.close()
a = a.to_i + 1 # Increment "a" by one to accomodate for consecutive papers 
a = a.to_s # Restore to string

end
```

Comment: What is your input file? Also, why not use an `each` loop instead of `for`?

Comment: The input file is listed in the same ruby program as an array.
l = Array.new
and then the following several hundred lines are the lines of the text.

Comment: Rather than building out a string and then making an array with `fedString.split`, you could start with `fedSections = []` and then, in your for loop, do `fedSections.push "Federalist No. #{f}"` -- look up Ruby's string interpolation rules for more info on why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your for loop

```
for k in 0...fedSections.length-1
```

you actually want

```
for k in 0..fedSections.length-1
```

`...` does not include the last element in the range

but as `screenmutt` said, it is more idiomatic ruby to use an `each` loop

```
fedSections.each do |section|
```

Comment: Should have used an `each`

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. I can't believe it was just a single dot that had me stuck for hours and hours.